# How can I say "concept association" in journalism?

Tags: word-request

Is there a specific name for when a journalist or a news network alters the order of news for any purpose?

I know for example on networks (at least in some countries) owned by some politician the news order is altered so that "good news" are near (in chronological order) to news about that politician, while bad news is mixed with news about some competitor.

I was searching on google for an article about that tecnique, but unluckily I can't find any because if I search for "Journalism topic association", the only search results are about Journalist societies.

I think I miss some word that could help me in the search. Thanks

Comment: Your question reminds me of the trope "manipulative editing".

Comment: You may want to try searches with the terms "stories," "pieces," or "segments" to refer to the discrete chunks of news in written or broadcast form.

Comment: Ah yeah, partially answer my question thanks :). Basically I had a friend "speaking about man", his article is titled "October, month of worms". And starts mentioning a press article of October of last year, and I wanted to make him notice (with a quoted source) he was basically associating man with worms (without explicitly saying that) in a way similiar to manipulative editing. Despite the fact I read about that tecnique multiple times (incurred randomly in such articles) I cannot find again the sources (and I periodically clear history of the browser u.u)

Comment: "Spin" is close, if too broad.

Comment: `spin journalism`
noun:

news and information that is manipulated or slanted to affect its interpretation and influence public opinion
.. Thanks! i would accept it as answer (yes is a bit too broad, but I don't know if a more specific term exists)

Comment: Journalistic, editorial or media bias are the usual terms that cover all of this - there's a well written Wikipedia article on this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_bias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Juxtaposition* is the name of the rhetorical device in which two or more ideas are put (chronologically) next to one another for effect. This can be used for artistic effect in literature, and it can be used in journalism to manipulate the reader's perception of facts. The concept of juxtaposition is quite general, as are most rhetorical devices (e.g. understatement, personification, metaphor, etc.).